# Selecting daily/hourly data

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, crosstab

I have to generate a report of the amount of tasks done per day, and per hour. This way, the report will look like a grid.

I'd like the days of the month (from 1 to 31) in the horizontal axis, and the hours (from 8:00 to 18:00) vertically.

How do I select this kind of data from a database using SQL in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Suppose i have a table called "tasks" with the fields id, date_time_of_task, fk_who_did_it

Comment: Have you made any `SELECT` statements in SQL before? If you know how to arrange the grid, then you're halfway there. Try to understand the logic used to construct it. I suggest making a few broad queries and posting your attempts, then others can come and help you refine your query to generate the report. You have to at least make some effort!

Comment: I know a bit of SQL... the problem is how to separate results per hour? I've never done that before =/

Comment: What data type are you using to store the time values?

Comment: I thought about select all the results ordered by date, and then group/ count id by time... but and about the gaps? I mean, the days that i dont have any tasks done, they won't appear... so, how to replace it by 0 (zero)... these are the things that makes me confused... =/

Comment: What RDBMS are you targetting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you are looking for is a SQL aggregation query.  It may seem a bit complicated, but the structure is pretty easy.

```
select extract(hour from date_time_of_task) as thehour,
       sum(case when extract(day from date_time_of_task) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as day_01,
       sum(case when extract(day from date_time_of_task) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as day_02,
       sum(case when extract(day from date_time_of_task) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as day_03,
       sum(case when extract(day from date_time_of_task) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as day_04,
       ... up to day 31
group by extract(hour from date_time_of_task)
order by 1
```

This is simply grouping by the hour of the day.  Then it pivots the data manually for each day of the month.  The "sum" counts the number of rows that meet the two conditions at the same time -- the hour of the row and the day of the column.

Comment: Good, i've tested both ways and got the expected results. Thx! =)

Answer (score 1):

The key elements to an elegant solution are [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html), [`date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and [`count(*)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html), [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) and finally: the [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) function (with 1 parameter) from the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html). To install it, run *once* per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab($x$

WITH x AS (
    SELECT date_part('day', date_time_of_task)::int AS d
          ,date_part('hour', date_time_of_task)::int AS h
          ,count(*)::int AS ct
    FROM   tasks
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    )
SELECT d, h, ct
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(1,31) AS d, generate_series(0,23) AS h) t
LEFT   JOIN x USING (d,h)
ORDER  BY 1,2

$x$)
AS orders(
 day int
,h8  int, h9  int, h10 int, h11 int, h12 int, h13 int, h14 int, h15 int
,h16 int, h17 int, h18 int);
```

Produces a matrix of days and hours with the count of tasks in each field like you describe.

BTW: I used this aux. function to generate the target definition list:

```
SELECT 'day int, ' || string_agg (x, ', ')
FROM (SELECT ('h' || generate_series(8,18) || ' int') AS x) a
```